# Windows 7 - How to find out what is blocking access to files

Tags: windows, windows-7, mcafee

There is a custom script that errors out when running is getting access denied. I looked at Process Mon from sysinternals but I don't see where it shows what is blocking access to a file/folder. I need to find out if it's the antivirus(without uninstalling it), previous iterations of the code, or something else that has a lock on the file. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you logging the activities and outputs from the script? If not, I would try getting that going. If so, is there an error being logged?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: not.

If it's AV/Screening/Driver stuff, the lock occurs in the (kernel) FS-API, which is not visible to processes in userland. If it's in Userland, the administrator's procmon or, with more comfort,  [handle.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/handle) will show the culprit to you.  You can use handle.exe to see the programs that have a file open, or to see the object types and names of all the handles of a program - IF there are such.